# How to change Dates format from text (Json string) in c# (or how to get date values from a long string)

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, asp.net-mvc, datetime

I have the Json string

```
....
{'ItemId':340,'LineId':340,'ItemName':'Trim 1_5A','ItemType':1},{'ItemId':341,'LineId':341,'ItemName':'Trim 1_5B','ItemType':1}]},'Success':true,'Errors':[],'OperationCanceled':false,'ErrorsConcatented':'','ResponseTime':'/Date(1425474069569)/'}

....

....
{'ItemId':350,'LineId':340,'ItemName':'Trim 1_5A','ItemType':1},{'ItemId':341,'LineId':341,'ItemName':'Trim 1_5B','ItemType':1}]},'Success':true,'Errors':[],'OperationCanceled':false,'ErrorsConcatented':'','ResponseTime':'/Date(1425474069569)/'}

....
```

That text have a datetime `'ResponseTime':'/Date(1425474069569)/`, I want to format( mm-dd-yyyy) this date from that string.

To deserialize the JSON I am using the JavaScriptSerializer.  When I try to deserialize my JSON I receive the following error:

> /Date(1425473984603)/ is not a valid value for DateTime

How can i do it? i have searched lot of in google, but cant get a solution :(

If is it possible, then please help me..

Comment: What are you using for JSON parsing ?

Comment: How are you deserializing your json ? In a class  what is the data type of the property  `ResponseTime` ?

Comment: Same  name of the property `ResponseTime `

Comment: Can you show your `c#` class your are deserializing  into ?

Comment: I can't , because that's a big length of data , so lot of properties there.

Comment: What is the datatype of the property `ResponseTime` in class ?? If it's datetime it will parse it as datetime. And when you need to show it on UI at that time use the `.ToString("yourformat")` to get what you want.

Comment: `DateTime` .  actually i have a long string with lot of dates , how can i  get the all dates from the string? once i get it then i can formate it ..

Comment: If you have valid `Json` object with the date values then just deserilize it in the class with matching properties.  And set the proper datatype for the properties . The conversion is handled by the `JavaScriptSerializer ` . To genrate the valid c# classes you can use the http://json2csharp.com/#

Comment: Yeah, the json string are serializing good. but i have a datetime problem only got. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSON can be parsed into objects that look like the JSON structure. For example,

```
{
    days: [
        {name: 'monday', value: 5}, 
        {name: 'tuesday', value: 7}
    ],
    week: 18
}
```

Will become an object with two properties: `days` and `week`.
You can then use the object just like any other C# object:

```
Console.WriteLine(parsed.week); //Prints 18
Console.WriteLine(parsed.days[0].name); //Prints 'Monday'
Console.WriteLine(parsed.days[1].value); //Prints 7
```

So, on to your actual data:

Your JSON example appears to be slightly malformed, so I modified the start a little bit to make a simple example.

Using [JSON.Net](https://json.codeplex.com/) (can be installed with NuGet), it can be done like this:

```
var jsonString = "{data: [{'ItemId':340,'LineId':340,'ItemName':'Trim 1_5A','ItemType':1},{'ItemId':341,'LineId':341,'ItemName':'Trim 1_5B','ItemType':1}],'Success':true,'Errors':[],'OperationCanceled':false,'ErrorsConcatented':'','ResponseTime':'/Date(1425474069569)/'}";
dynamic data = JValue.Parse(jsonString);

Console.WriteLine(data.ResponseTime); //this is your DateTime object
Console.WriteLine(data.ResponseTime.ToString("mm-dd-yyyy")); //Formatted like you wanted it
```

---

EDIT: Without packages. How about using System.Web.Helpers.Json?

```
dynamic data = System.Web.Helpers.Json.Decode(jsonString);

Console.WriteLine(data.ResponseTime); ///Date(1425474069569)/

//Now we need to create a DateTime object from this string.
var timeString = data.ResponseTime.Replace("/Date(", "").Replace(")/",""); //Remove the wrapping
var seconds = long.Parse(timeString)/1000; //Parse the number, and turn it into seconds (it was milliseconds)
var date = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0).AddSeconds(seconds); //Create a new DateTime object starting on the Unix date, and add the seconds
Console.WriteLine(date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

And if you don't even have System.Web.Helpers, you could also parse the string manually (Regex.Split, String.Split, String.Replace, etc), and use the above method of creating a DateTime object from the date string.

Comment: i don't want add any package for this topic, is it possible without add any packages?

Comment: Edited in one way to do it without any additional packages.

Comment: Is it okay, But how can i get the `ResponseTime`? i have a lot of `ResponseTime` property in the json string

Comment: When deserializing Json using one of the two methods above, you get objects that are formed like the Json. That means that you can use data.ResponseTime (like I did -- the code above is everything you need), or, if you parse the entire JSON string you have, probably something like data.Objects[i].ResponseTime. It's just like a normal object.

Comment: Added a section at the top of my answer to hopefully make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You should deserialize the JSON string into an object.

You can use Newtonsoft JSON, JavaScriptSerializer [Deserilize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb355316%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), or something else.  After you have deserialized the JSON content in C#, you will have a DateTime object for the ResponseTime property.  Once you have the date object you can give the date format like so...

```
string mystring = String.Format("{0:MM-dd-yyyy}", dt);          // "03-09-2008"
```

where dt is your DateTime object and mystring is the string value...

[MSDN Custom Date Time formats doc](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

**For Deserialization error**

error is /Date(1425473984603)/ is not a valid value for DateTime.

check the slashes in your date here is a similar deserialization error with date objects and JavaScriptSerializer

[Date Issue with JavaScriptSerializer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852432/using-net-javascriptserializer-deserialize-with-datetime-from-client)

Comment: I  don't have datetime object, i have a json text only

Comment: You should deserialize your JSON into an object with corresponding properties.  There are a number of serializers you can use.  You can use Newtonsoft https://www.nuget.org/packages/Newtonsoft.Json/ or the JavaScriptSerializer to deserialize your object...

Comment: I am using `JavaScriptSerializer `  i got a error when i deserialize  my object.

Comment: You never mentioned you got an error when deserializing your object.  Can you include that info?  Also i answered your original question assuming you deserialized the JSON...

Comment: Also if you could include the class you are trying to deserialize the JSON into would help.

Comment: What error you have  when you deserialize your object ?

Comment: error is  `/Date(1425473984603)/ is not a valid value for DateTime.`

Comment: check the slashes http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852432/using-net-javascriptserializer-deserialize-with-datetime-from-client

Answer (score 0):

if Date is in this format D:20181116110130+05'30' or  D:20181116110130-05'30'

```
 private static string ConvertInToDateTime(string DateTime)
    {
        string[] SplitDate = DateTime.Split(':');
        string[] SplitDateTime = null;
        if (SplitDate[1].Contains("+"))
            SplitDateTime = SplitDate[1].Split('+');
        else if (SplitDate[1].Contains("-"))
            SplitDateTime = SplitDate[1].Split('-');
        string TimeStamp = SplitDateTime[0].Insert(12, ":").Insert(10, ":").Insert(8, " ").Insert(6, "-").Insert(4, "-");
        return TimeStamp;
    }
```