# c# loop through json data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2005

I have a json like this:

```
[{ "Demand": 4422.45, "Supply": 17660, "Date": "/Date(1236504600000)/", "DateString": "3 PM" },  
{ "Demand": 4622.88, "Supply": 7794, "Date": "/Date(1236522600000)/", "DateString": "8 PM" }, 
{ "Demand": 545.65, "Supply": 2767, "Date": "/Date(1236583800000)/", "DateString": "1 PM" }, 
{ "Demand": 0, "Supply": 1, "Date": "/Date(1236587400000)/", "DateString": "2 PM" }];
```

How do i loop through each item in vs2005 c#? Please don't suggest newtonsoft deserialize as it does not work in my vs2005 solution. Also I cannot use "var" keyword in vs2005.

thanks.

Comment: well as you probably know you should deserialize it based on the model you create from your json then you have a list of that model then you can loop through the list

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [`DataContractJsonSerializer`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.serialization.json.datacontractjsonserializer(v=vs.110).aspx) class that's part of the `System.Runtime.Serialization` assembly. Start by writing a model that will represent this entity:

```
public class MyModel
{
    public decimal Demand { get; set; }
    public decimal Supply { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string DateString { get; set; }
}
```

and then deserialize the JSON string to a list of this model:

```
string json = "[{ \"Demand\": 4422.45, \"Supply\": 17660, \"Date\": \"/Date(1236504600000)/\", \"DateString\": \"3 PM\" },  { \"Demand\": 4622.88, \"Supply\": 7794, \"Date\": \"/Date(1236522600000)/\", \"DateString\": \"8 PM\" }, { \"Demand\": 545.65, \"Supply\": 2767, \"Date\": \"/Date(1236583800000)/\", \"DateString\": \"1 PM\" }, { \"Demand\": 0, \"Supply\": 1, \"Date\": \"/Date(1236587400000)/\", \"DateString\": \"2 PM\" }]";
DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<MyModel>));
using (Stream stream = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(json)))
{
    List<MyModel> models = (List<MyModel>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);
    foreach (MyModel model in models)
    {
        // do something with the model here
        Console.WriteLine(model.Date);
    }
}
```

---

UPDATE:

It looks like you are using some prehistoric version of C# which doesn't support auto properties. In this case you will need a private field for each property:

```
public class MyModel
{
    private decimal demand;
    public decimal Demand 
    { 
        get { return this.demand; }
        set { this.demand = value; }
    }

    private decimal supply;
    public decimal Supply 
    { 
        get { return this.supply; }
        set { this.supply = value; }
    }

    private DateTime date;
    public DateTime Date
    { 
        get { return this.date; }
        set { this.supply = value; }
    }

    private string dateString;
    public string DateString
    { 
        get { return this.dateString; }
        set { this.dateString = value; }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Darin for the reply. I am getting error - Supply.get' must declare a body because it is not marked abstract or extern - do you have any idea why it is coming?

Comment: It seems that you are using some very old C# version which doesn't support auto properties. In this case you will need to have a private field for each property: `private decimal demand; public Decimal Demand { get { return this.demand; } set { this.demand = value; } }`. And so on for the other properties. I will update my answer with an example.

Comment: Darin - do you know what can I use instead of var as it gies error - The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: Another error I am getting is - The best overloaded method match for 'System.Runtime.Serialization.XmlObjectSerializer.ReadObject(System.IO.Stream)' has some invalid arguments

Comment: `XmlObjectSerializer`? Where does this come from? Which version of the .NET framework are you using? I am not sure that the `DataContractJsonSerializer` class is available in the old versions.

Comment: On this line - List<MyModel> models = (List<MyModel>)serializer.ReadObject(stream);                                            Also this line says - cannot convert from 'var' to 'System.IO.Stream

Comment: You can replace `var` with `Stream`. Once again: which version of the .NET framework are you targeting? Maybe you are wasting your time with `DataContractJsonSerializer` as it is not available. This class has been introduced in .NET 3.5, so if you are using something older it will not work.

Comment: I think it is 2.0 :(

Comment: Ohh, then you are out of luck. There are no built-in JSON serializers in .NET 2.0. You could use some old version of JSON.NET which supports .NET 2.0.

Comment: Thanks Darin Dimitrov for all the patience and suggestions, appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Another approach it would be to use the `JavaScriptSerializer`, which is part of the `System.Web.Extensions` assembly.

You will need a model, that represents your data:

```
public class Data
{
    public decimal Demand { get; set; }
    public int Supply { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public string DateString { get; set; }
}
```

Then you just need this:

```
string json = "[{\"Demand\": 4422.45,\"Supply\": 17660,\"Date\":\"\\/Date(1236504600000)\\/\",\"DateString\":\"3 PM\" },{\"Demand\": 4622.88, \"Supply\": 7794, \"Date\": \"\\/Date(1236522600000)\\/\", \"DateString\": \"8 PM\" }]";
JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Data> result = serializer.Deserialize<List<Data>>(json);
```

*Note*: Please note that Date property in the json. I added some extra characters: `\"\\/Date(1236504600000)\\/\"`. Unfortunately, neither `DataContractJsonSerializer` nor `JavaScriptSerializer` can deserialize "/Date(1236504600000)/", you need defenitely these extra characters. If you are the producer and the consumer of this json, then you can handle this in client fairly easily as it is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11852432/using-net-javascriptserializer-deserialize-with-datetime-from-client). Otherwise some similar approach should be followed server side, before you deserialize the json that client sends to you.

Comment: Christos - thank you for the reply.  i am getting error - The type or namespace name 'var' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?). How do I resolve this?

Comment: @user1254053 My bad...Sorry..I forgot that you can't use the `var` keyword.

Comment: Now it build successfully but on browser gives error on this line List<Data> result = serializer.Deserialize<List<Data>>(json);   - Invalid JSON primitive: http.

Comment: @user1254053 Did you check the notice? Does the json you have has the same format as the one of the answer? Pay attention on Date. Might this be the case. The json you have can't be parsed by neither the `JavaScriptSerializer` nor `DataContractJsonSerializer`? Some extra work is needed.

Comment: I have modified it and made the simple json - class MyData
    {
        public string Name;
        public DateTime ExpiryDate;
        public float Price;
        public string[][] Sizes;
    }             <br/> string json = "{\"Name\": \"Apple\",  \"ExpiryDate\": \"2008-12-28T00:00:00\",  \"Price\": 3.99,  \"Sizes\": [   \"Small\",    \"Medium\",    \"Large\"  ]}";

        JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        List<MyData> result = serializer.Deserialize<List<MyData>>(json);

Comment: Here I don't get any results in result variable

Comment: As it seems, from your data, `Sizes` is an array of strings and and array of array's of string as you have declared. In terms of code, this `string[][] Sizes` should change to this `string[] Sizes`.

Comment: Yes I did that but still the result has nothing -- 0 dimension

Comment: @user1254053 I am not sure, if that's the case, but you have to use the properties definition also. I mean instead of declaring `public string[] Sizes`  you should declare it as `public string[] Sizes { get; set; }`. This should happen for all your fields. Instead of fields you should have properties.